# Tooling API 'No Access to entity:TraceFlag'

Tags: tooling-api

The Tooling API brings a new object with it, that allows me to create Apex Logs programmatically. It's called TraceFlag.
I tried to implement it in my na15 org (28.0) but i get a

> No access to entity: TraceFlag

warning.

I just use [Developer's Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_toolingpre/api_tooling.pdf) code:

```
    TraceFlag traceFlag = new TraceFlag();
    traceFlag.ApexCode = 'Finest' ;
    traceFlag.ApexProfiling = 'Finest' ;
    traceFlag.Callout = 'Info' ;
    traceFlag.Database = 'Finest' ;
    traceFlag.System = 'Debug' ;
    traceFlag.Validation = 'Info' ;
    traceFlag.Visualforce = 'Info' ;
    traceFlag.Workflow = 'Info' ;
    //set an expiration date
    traceFlag.ExpirationDate = myTimestamp;
    //set the ID of the user to monitor 
    traceFlag.TracedEntityId = runAs.Id ;
    //call the create method 
    TraceFlag[] traceFlags =new TraceFlag[] {traceFlag};
    SaveResult[] traceResults = sforce.create(traceFlags);
    for ( int i = 0; i < traceResults.Length; i++)
    {
        if (traceResults[i].success) {
           System.debug( 'Successfully created trace flag: ' + traceResults[i].id);
        }
        else {
            System.debug( 'Error: could not create trace flag ' );
            System.debug( ' The error reported was: ' +
                            traceResults[i].errors[0].message + '\n' );
        }
    }
```

Do I need to create it via REST API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please remember that the Tooling API is meant to be called from outside Salesforce.com. The examples in the Summer '13 docs look like Apex but as far as I know this is a JAVA exampple.

If you want to use features of the Tooling API from inside Apex you first need to learn how to call this API from APEX.

Maybe those questions / web articles help in doing that:

- [Summer’13 Pre-Release : Metadata API, Tooling API and Apex
  Mocking?](http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/04/21/summer13-pre-release-metadata-api-tooling-api-and-apex-mocking/) by Andrew Fawcett
- [Spring Cleaning Apex Code with the
  Tooling API](http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/02/02/spring-cleaning-apex-code-with-the-tooling-api/)

Comment: but look what I found on StackExchange: "The naming of the ToolingAPI is a little confusing. It's really just a new set of components (sObjects for the most part) that are layered on top of the standard REST or SOAP APIs."[@Ralph]
(And it's not even possible to declarate a null TraceFlag object)